# Where to put constants for data models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am making ASP.NET core MVC project. In one Solution I have some assemblies - `.Data`, `.Services`, `.Web`. In the `.Data` there are the Models (for the database), DbContext, Migration etc. For the models I use `DataAnnotations`, but when there are some "magic" numbers like 100 (for the maximum length of the "Name" property) I prefer to use constants.
For example `[MaxLength(CourseConstants.NameMaxLength)]`. These constants I can use them in the ".Web" assemblie. For example when someone is making a course and I can restrict the maximum length of the name using the same constant like in the "Course" model.

So my question is - where to put the constants ? One way is in the separate class (example - "CourseConstants"). But I think that for better cohesion I should put the constants that are used for the "Course" model inside the "Course" class. And if I need them in ".Services" or in ".Web" I should call them from the Course class - example `Course.NameMaxLength`.

P.S. sorry if I dont follow some of the rules in this site and community, its my first question here.

CASE 1:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(CourseConstants.NameMaxLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(CourseConstants.DescriptionMaxlenght)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User Trainer { get; set; }
    public string TrainerId { get; set; }
}

public class CourseConstants    
{
    public const int NameMaxLength = 100;

    public const int DescriptionMaxlenght = 200;
}
```

CASE 2:

```
public class Course
{
    public const string NameMaxLength = 100;
    public const string DescriptionMaxlenght= 200;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(NameMaxLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(DescriptionMaxlenght)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User Trainer { get; set; }
    public string TrainerId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common reason to separate models in a different project is that you might want to reuse them for other applications. For example you have an API and it returns some models in JSON format and you would want to use the exact same model in an application that consumes that API, since it's the same. Even better, when someone changes the class, it gets updated in your app as well.

Your question, though, relates to data models used inside the data access layer. These models should only be used in your business classes and, of course, in the DAL. They should not be reusable outside the scope of the DAL and projects that access data. If you want to make them consumable from the outside, you would map them to API models that would be different classes than EF classes.

That said, constants should be part of the DAL project, together with the EF data classes, since they should not be reused anywhere else. The only reason why you would put them somewhere else would be as an assembly to share between projects with constants like PersonNameLength or EmailLength or something like that.

Comment: Let's say that i have class CouseFormModel in the ".web" project that will be used to create a new Course (controller> service>DbContext). I could use NameMaxLength from the ".data" project to constaint maximum length of the property name in class "CourseFormModel". In that way there will by sync between the name property of "Course" and the nape property of "CourseFormModel". So int that case isn't it better to have that constant NameMaxLength ? If answer is yes - where to put it, that was my question.

Comment: So you have a .web project (the website, I guess), then a .data project (data access layer). Best practice would be to also have a .business project, that holds your logic decoupled from the UI. In that case, I would place that constant in a .common project that holds just constants and other overall reuse code. .common would be then referenced by .data (where the course entity is) and .business (where the course model is). All this would be so that .web does NOT reference .data in any way or form.

Comment: If .web is also your business layer, then it already references .data so you could place the constant there. But this is a bad practice for the reason that anything trying to use a simple length constraint will have to reference the entirety of your data layer.